# 401 Error - Call REST API secured with AZURE Active Directory (JavaScript Client)

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, http-status-code-401, rest

**Hi All,**

I got a scenario in which i am supposed to call a REST api that is secured by a **AZURE ACTIVE DIRECTORY**. Most of the code runs fine and i am able to get the token using **myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent** function too.

**401 ERROR COMES WHEN I SEND AJAX CALL USING THAT TOKEN, YOU CAN SEE FOLLOWING CODE**

User is there in Active Directory for which i get proper token, i dont know why my ajax call fails when i send that token to rest-api, please help

```
    
<script type="text/javascript">

    const msalConfig = {
        auth: {
            clientId: "94edf294-08ae-489f-8621-c6d98009afa8", 
            authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/c483b3c4-21a6-4c93-95ea-7436cf318a68",
            redirectUri: "https://localhost:44334/",
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
            storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
        }
    };

    const myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);

    function CallApi() {
        // Add scopes for the id token to be used at Microsoft identity platform endpoints.
        const loginRequest = {
            scopes: ["User.Read"],
        };

        myMSALObj.loginPopup(loginRequest)
            .then((loginResponse) => {

                const accessTokenRequest = {
                    scopes: ["api://8c2b0253-f9e8-442c-bccf-b4a8bbe73b59/access_as_user"]
                };

                myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest).then((accessTokenResponse) => {
                    var accessToken = accessTokenResponse.accessToken;
                    var apiEndpoint = "https://localhost:44387/api/hello";
                    var bearer = "Bearer " + accessToken;
                    console.log("accessToken = ", accessToken);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: apiEndpoint,
                        type: "GET",
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", bearer) }
                    }).done(function (response) {
                        alert("SUCCESS");
                        console.log("response = ", JSON.stringify(response));
                    }).fail(function (err) {
                        console.error("Error Occurred");
                        console.log("error = ", JSON.stringify(err));
                    });

                })

            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
</script>
```

Screenshot of a NEW API Code
[image]

Screenshot of JWT.ms (Access Token)
[image]
[image]

**New Screenshot of JWT Token**
[image]

Comment: Have you exposed your API to the client app registration?

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your token and provide a screenshot. You must ensure that the scope requested by the client application is consistent with the expected recipient of the token. Check your `aud`  to ensure that it is the api you want to call, and the reason for the 401 You may have used the wrong token or you have used a token that does not belong to the api to call the api.

Comment: @Purushothaman:
yes, i exposed the Web-Api and also added the Client-App Id in web-api (i will attach screenshot too)

Comment: @CarlZhao i attached the screenshots; timestamps look good also the api urls are good. still dont know why i am getting 401 error

Comment: @Imran  Have you tried to add api application permission for the client application, go to client application>API permissions>Add a permission>My APIs>api application>add>Grant admin consent.

Comment: @Carl Zhao - Yes i have ... but it still doesn't work. Is there any special thing we need to do while adding a new user ?

Comment: @Purushothaman  I don't see any problems with your code. I think the problem still occurs in your apiEndpoint. Is your apiEndpoint a custom api? Make sure it is your token recipient.

Comment: @Carl Zhao - Thanks a lot for doing follow up. yes, i think its my API. I watched a video on PluralSight and followed steps. There is definitely something wrong in that .... 

Can you please give me a sample API project that is compatible with my MSAL client app .... i will change ClientId and other ids in your sample App (like tenantId etc) 

really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Carl Zhao - i also attached the screenshot of my API code

Comment: You can find details of implementing authentication and authorization in web api in this docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration

Comment: https://cmatskas.com/create-a-protected-api-that-calls-in-ms-graph-on-behalf-of-a-power-app/

Comment: awesome, i will follow this article tomorrow and will update your guys here ... thanks again for you help, stay blessed

Comment: @ Purushothaman - I followed the steps mentioned in the **[article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration)** and this time i see some error in Network Tab its says invalid_token and the full description is **www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience 'api://8c2b0253-f9e8-442c-bccf-b4a8bbe73b59' is invalid"** please also see my NEW API code attaching the screenshot

Comment: You can see in attached screenshots that my **AUD** in JWT token screenshot is the same that my ajax call is complaining about (in developer tools - chrome browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, Following call was missing in my **startup.cs** file

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

thanks for your help guys

Specially - **@Carl Zhao, @Purushothaman @Rass Masood**

Answer (score 1):

You should not set the `client ID` in the `appsettings.json file` to the `client id` of your `api app`. It should be the client id of your `client app`. According to the jwt analysis diagram you provided, I think it should be: `94edf294- 08ae-489f-8621-c6xxxxxxx`.

[image]

Comment: i will try it today

Comment: I just tried and got the same error ... i just attached a new screenshot to this question. Please check that

Comment: @Imran  You may have misunderstood what I mean, I mean you should change the **client id** in the **appsettings.json file** to: 94edf294- 08ae-489f-8621-c6xxxxxxx.

Comment: Yes, i changed the **ClientId in appsettings.json** file and then attached the new screenshot of the JWT token that was showing new ClientId.